# Problems with Spring Localization: cant switch lang

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localization, locale

I have this Spring configuration for my applecation, shown below

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
      id="messageSource"
      p:basename="resources/l18n/label"/>
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
        id="localeResolver"
        p:cookieName="locale"
        p:defaultLocale="en"/>
```

when i run my application default lang always ru although i set en(`p:defaultLocale="en"`) also when i change suffix my URL on `?lang=en` nothing has changed, everything is also ru. When i tried to delete `label_ru` i got this exeption:
 `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'jumbotron.h1' for locale 'ru'`

Web.xml :

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Phone Book</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: you have the problem on all pages ?

Comment: @davidhxxx i try make locale only on one pages

Comment: which page ? Can you show your web.xml ?

Comment: @davidhxxx i added web.xml, and i make locale on welcome pages

Comment: @davidhxxx so i tried make localization of another page which has controller and this earned, so i think i should make controller to main page

Comment: You could try it. The problem may come from the welcome-file which is not handled by the Spring Interceptor. So, yes make that Spring handle it.

Comment: @davidhxxx, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For avoid this problem your shoudt not use tag below on your web.xml file

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```